# como gerar uma tabela com uma array de tamanho 228

Tags: php

```
echo "<script>console.log(\"".sizeOf($status)."\");</script>";
```

Essa *array* tem tamanho de 228.
Dentro dessa *array* há `nome`, `status1`, `status2`, `status3`, `status4`. (5 colunas).
Queria imprimi-las em forma de tabela.

```
if($status[$i]['numStatus'] == 1){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$status[$i]['Nome']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $status[$i]['status'] . "</td>".PHP_EOL;

} else if($status[$i]['numStatus'] == 2) {
    echo "<td>" . $status[$i]['status'] . "</td>".PHP_EOL;

} else if($status[$i]['numStatus'] == 3){
    echo "<td>" . $status[$i]['status'] . "</td>".PHP_EOL;

} else if ($status[$i]['numStatus'] == 4){
    echo "<td>" . $status[$i]['status'] . "</td>".PHP_EOL;

    echo  "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Fiz desse jeito, mas acho que há um jeito melhor, não é?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que sua lista vai vir em ordem, da pra fazer algo assim:

```
$qtdeColunas = 4; // 4 porque ele gera 2 na primeira vez, totalizando 5
$i = 0;

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
for (;$i < sizeOf($status);$i++) {

    if ($i % $qtdeColunas == 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        echo "<td>".$status[$i]['Nome']."</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . $status[$i]['status'] . "</td>";
}

//Adiciona as tds caso tiver faltando algum pra dar as 5 colunas no final
while ($i <= $qtdeColunas) {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```